# Trying to get the sum of arrays' element recursively

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to find the sum of the elements of an array recursively on c++.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int findSum(int arr[], int b, int e)
{
    if(b == e)
        return arr[b];
    else
    {
        int mid = (b + e) / 2;
        int x = findSum(arr, b, mid);
        int y = findSum(arr, mid, e);

        return x + y;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 6, 3, 10, 11, 4, 5, 9, 15, 2};

    cout << findSum(arr, 0, 9);

    cout << endl; system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

After running, I get(Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault)

Comment: The enclosures in this (where you're partitioning) need a thorough review. You ave a small data set. Get a paper and pencil and draw out, line by line, in a tree, what happens *exactly* with each recursion. Then, single step in a debugger to confirm or assail your paper-conclusion.

Comment: BTW why are you using such complicated way of recursively summing the elements? Why not simply: `findSum(arr, i+1)`

Comment: @DavideSpataro, can you please explain more with some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the problem is in your code has been well explained in the answer from 
[VladFromMoscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow).

---

Anyway here is a simpler recursive solution for summing the elements of a collection:

You can keep a variable telling you which index of the array you are considering at the moment and when that is larger than the size of the array, you can return `0` i.e. the neutral element for sum.

Otherwise, you simply sum `arr[i]` to the sum of the **rest** of the array.

```
int findSum(const int arr[], const int i, const int size)
{
    if(i > size)
        return 0;
    return arr[i]+findSum(arr, i+1, size);
}
```

I find it easier on the eyes =)

Comment: It is not the approach used by the author of the question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I only put it as an answer because he asked explicitely for it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do anything recursively in c++ is hazardous. Yout program would be at risk of a stack overflow, as it has multiple duplicates of a function filling the stack, growing larger every time it calls itself.

Thus, here is how you can do it iteratively:

```
 long int findsum(const int array[], int elementstart, int elementend) {
    long int summedArray = 0;
    for (int currentcell = elementstart; currentcell <= elementend; ++currentcell)
        summedArray += array[currentcell];
    return summedArray;
 }
```

Comment: FFS, if we're going that route, why not just use `std::cout << std::accumulate(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0) << '\n';`

Comment: Did'nt think of that :D sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your function is incorrect. For example if the array has only one element then the function returns 0.

Apart from this if the array contains two elements then you are passing indices b = 0, e = 1. Then the middle index is equal to 0 ( ( b + e ) / 2 == 0 ) and you are again recursively calling the function with the same values b = 0 and e = 1. So there is an infinite recursion.

You should specify the range as [begin index, index after the last ].

But in any case the function can be written simpler. Ywo indices are redundant.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written.

```
#include <iostream>

long long int findSum( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    return 
    n == 0 ? 0 
           : ( n == 1 ? *a 
                      : findSum( a, n / 2 ) + findSum( a + n / 2, n - n / 2 ) );
}

int main() 
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 6, 3, 10, 11, 4, 5, 9, 15, 2 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

    std::cout << findSum (arr, N ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
66
```

Comment: Don't really like that `return`, think 3 seperate `return` staments in `if` blocks would be easier on the eyes. Upvoted anyway - good answer!